# UICollectionView.reloadData() Design Error

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

When i did cv.reloadData my cells is broken.

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieYbh.png)

[Last](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEHcM.png)

When i write answer and click send button run this func.

```
func checkPlay(playedWord : String) {
    if WordCheck(word: playedWord) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        if isGameOver() {
            //alert end save user default if score is max? and do proccess
        }
    }
}
```

If i get to comment cv.reloadData() func. My design is be safe but not writing answer.

I'm so sory for my bad English

Comment: What does WordCheck function do ?

Comment: That check playedword in results.

Comment: Can you please share some more code? From the above nothing seems to mess with your UI